# Problems with computing the entropy of random variables via SciPy (stats)

Tags: python, scipy, entropy

Recently I've been trying to figure out how to calculate the entropy of a random variable X using

```
sp.stats.entropy()
```

from the stats package of SciPy, with this random variable X being the returns I obtain from the stock of a specific company ("Company 1") from 1997 to 2012 (this is for a financial data/machine learning assignment). However, the arguments involve inputting the probability values

```
pk
```

and so far I'm even struggling with computing the actual empirical probabilities, seeing as I only have the observations of the random variable. I've tried different ways of normalising the data in order to obtain an array of probabilities, but my data contains negative values too, which means that when I try and do

```
asset1/np.sum(asset1)
```

where asset1 is the row array of the returns of the stock of "Company 1", I manage to obtain a new array which adds up to 1, but obviously with some negative values, and as we all know, negative probabilities do not exist. Therefore, is there any way of computing the empirical probabilities of my observations occurring again (ideally with the option of choosing specific bins, or for a range of values) on Python?

Furthermore, I've been trying to look for a Python package for countless hours which is solely dedicated to the calculation of random variable entropies, joint entropies, mutual information etc. as an alternative to SciPy's entropy option (simply to compare) but most seem to be outdated (I currently have Python 3.5), hence does anyone know of any good package which is compatible with my current version of Python? I know R seems to have a very compact one.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: stock returns are considered to be RANDOM VARIABLES, as opposed to the stock prices which are processes. Therefore, the entropy can definitely be applied in this context.

Comment: Could you share the value of `asset1`?

Comment: Yes sure, it's really long though (it's 4025 by 1):

    array([ 0.0256895 , -0.0054496 ,  0.00181982, ..., -0.0010976 ,
       -0.01294823,  0.00870327])

Comment: `scipy.stats.entropy()` computes the entropy of a discrete distribution, not the entropy of a sample.

Comment: Your problem is not well-defined. You have a single realization of a random *process*, yet you are requesting the entropy which is a quantity defined for a random *variable*.

Comment: @Jayjay95 Are these the unnormalized data?

Comment: See [Entropy estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation) and the references there for some ideas on how to estimate the entropy from an observation.

Comment: @kennytm yes they are, it's the raw unnormalised data.

Comment: @Stelios no, you're wrong, stock returns are always assumed to be random variables, as opposed to the price, which follow a Geometric Brownian Motion. I do see why you thought that it was a process, I did mention that the returns are from 1997 to 2012 after all, but no, the returns are a random variable, so the entropy can definitely be applied in this situation. There are plenty of papers where Shannon's entropy is applied to the context of finance, especially towards stock returns, but most seem to skip the technicalities and how it's all computed.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you, but my problem isn't the maths behind the method of calculating Shannon's entropy, but the way of how to compute it and implementing it onto Python - I'm relatively new, which is why I'm struggling on such a simple part. I'm also aware that I need to use the distribution, but this is the problem, I can't seem to find a way of finding the empirical probabilities of my observations on Python.

Comment: @Jayjay95 Fair enough, although I would expect that the stock return values are correlated. If you treat the values as samples from a random variable, you have the following problem: `entropy()` is defined for discrete-valued random variables, whereas the stock return is continuous-valued. I would suggest asking advice from a more appropriate stack exchange site, as this issue is irrelevant to python/scipy implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For continuous distributions, you are better off using the Kozachenko-Leonenko k-nearest neighbour estimator for entropy (K & L 1987) and the corresponding Kraskov, ..., Grassberger (2004) estimator for mutual information. These circumvent the intermediate step of calculating the probability density function, and estimate the entropy directly from the distances of data point to their k-nearest neighbour.

The basic idea of the Kozachenko-Leonenko estimator is to look at (some function of) the average distance between neighbouring data points. The intuition is that if that distance is large, the dispersion in your data is large and hence the entropy is large. In practice, instead of taking the nearest neighbour distance, one tends to take the k-nearest neighbour distance, which tends to make the estimate more robust.

I have implementations for both on my github:
https://github.com/paulbrodersen/entropy_estimators

The code has only been tested using python 2.7, but I would be surprised if it doesn't run on 3.x.